# Twilio Chat Angular JS - 403 forbidden error

Tags: angularjs, http-status-code-403, twilio-programmable-chat

Integrated a Chat in one of my application. After some time of using the application, the chat API returns forbidden - 403 error unexpectedly.

[image: error message]

How can I resolve this issue? I need to publish the application to live.

Comment: A 403 means it trying to hit an unauthorized request and hence forbidden. Keep your network tab open to verify all the calls. It is also possible that your session cookie is getting expired and hence any xhr request is forbidden